# How to make <div> tag behave as <a> tag for the mouse right click event?

Tags: html

Is there a way to show "Open Link in New Tab", and "Open Link in New Window" etc.. by right-clicking on a div tag as same as an "a" tag with href attribute?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. Even with JavaScript, as in obsergiu's answer, it may be blocked by the users browser as it'll be treated as a popup window. You could simply use `<a>` then the CSS style `display: block; text-decoration: none; cursor: default;` to make it act like a `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the JavaScript to offer a custom  right click menu:

```
el.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    alert('Custom menu !');
    return false;
}, false);
```